# Chakra UI __css on sub-component isn't being applied when styling multipart components

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using Typescript, React(create-react-app) and Chakra.
As in the title, css on `<DropdownItem>` component isn't being applied.
Css on `<Dropdown>` works normally.
I have this code basically copied from the [styling multipart components](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#styling-multipart-components) and when comparing it to the List component from the Chakra [source code](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/96117054388ec4078b0c58ff3a0f6f9c3c8cd5c9/packages/layout/src/list.tsx), it looks okay to me. But it doesn't work for some reason.
There is no errors and when console logging the CSSDict from `useStyles()` and `useMultiStyleConfig()` it logs the styles normally. I think it must be breaking at `__css={styles.item}`.
Thank you in advance.

#### Select.tsx

```
<Dropdown onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
      <DropdownItem>{currItem}</DropdownItem>
</Dropdown>
```

---

#### Dropdown.tsx

```
const [StylesProvider, useStyles] = createStylesContext("Dropdown");

export function Dropdown(props: any): any {
  const { size, variant, children, ...rest } = props;
  const styles = useMultiStyleConfig("Dropdown", { size, variant });
  return (
    <List __css={styles.dropdown} {...rest}>
      <StylesProvider value={styles}>{children}</StylesProvider>
    </List>
  );
}

export function DropdownItem(props: any): any {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return <ListItem __css={styles.item} {...props} />;
}
```

---

#### theme.ts

```
export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Button,
    Dropdown,
  },
  colors: {
    main: {
      independence: "#3D405B",
      purplenavy: "#51557A",
      darkbluegray: "#656A99",
      terracotta: "#E07A5F",
      eggshell: "#F4F1DE",
    },
  },
  styles: {
    global: () => ({
      body: {
        bg: "main.independence",
        height: "100%",
      },
    }),
  },
  shadows: {
    terra: "2px -2px #E07A5F",
    eggshell: "2px -2px #F4F1DE",
  },
});
```

---

#### database.style.ts

```
export const Dropdown: ComponentStyleConfig = {
  parts: ["dropdown", "item"],
  // The base styles for each part
  baseStyle: {
    dropdown: {
      position: "relative",
      display: "inline-block",
      width: "100px",
      cursor: "pointer",
      fontSize: "calc(35px, 0.87vw)",
      h: "100%",
      zIndex: "10",
    },
    item: {
      h: "100%",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      _hover: { bg: "main.violetLt", borderRadius: "15px 0 0 15px" },
      fontWeight: "600",
      bg: "orange",
    },
  },
  // The size styles for each part
  sizes: {},
  // The variant styles for each part
  variants: {},
  // The default `size` or `variant` values
  defaultProps: {},
};
```

[image]

#### Edit 1

Looking at it from React Devtools, `<ListElement>` is the last component that gets the correct __css prop, which then disappears in `<li>` child.

[image]

## Edit 2

```
export function DropdownItem(props: any): any {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return <chakra.li __css={styles.item} {...props} />;
}
```

Using `<chakra.li>` instead of `<ListElement>` somehow solves the problem and the css is being passed and applied but I still don't understand why.